# Change image on click of button

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a basic app where once you click the button the image changes randomly to one of the 7 `.png`images I have loaded.  I've tried several different ways but can't seem to get it to work.  Here's my code as of now:

**.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:text="@string/black" 
       android:onClick="onClick"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**.java**

```
public class Black extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.black);
    }

    public void onClick() {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);

        int[] picture={R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcircle,R.drawable.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
         Random r = new Random();
         int n=r.nextInt(7);
         imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);
    }
}
```

My error message in Eclipse says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post your manifest and your FULL logcat.

Comment: Post the ComponentInfo Class, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
public class Black extends Activity {
 ImageView imageView;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.black);
   imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
 }


public void onClick() {



    int[] picture=  

   {
     R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcircle,R.drawabl    e.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
     Random r = new Random();
     int n=r.nextInt(7);
     imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvote: How should this work? The onClick listener is never assigned! @No_Rulz has a correct example. Also why are you using an anonymous block? Will not work!

Comment: Will remove the downvote, if you edit your answer to be a working helpful code example!

Comment: @elton:click event is assigned to button in xml file...just check layout code in question

Comment: I needed to add "(View view)" to the "public void onClick()" but this worked perfect.  Thanks user2260168.

Comment: if you found this helpful then please tick upvote  & accept it

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
public class Black extends Activity implements onClickListener{
 ImageView imageView;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.black);
     imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
     imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if(v == imgView){

    int[] picture=  

   {
     R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcircle,R.drawabl    e.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
     Random r = new Random();
     int n=r.nextInt(7);
     imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Random r=new Random();
r=(int)(Math.random()*7);
imageview.setImageResource(picture[r]);`